# What is the suitable Import and JAR file for SessionFactory and Configuration()

Tags: java, hibernate

I used SessionFactory and Configuration() in my code. I did eclipse suggested imports, But while placing my mouse on "SessionFactory" my eclipse is showing suggestion like create a local variable 'SessionFactory' and create a field, a parameter of SessionFactory and Remove Assignment.

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

I tried the above Imports, but it's not worked for me

```
public class CreateStudentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create Session Factory
        SessionFactory = new Configuration()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();

        // Create Session 
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {
            //use session object to save java object

    }
        finally{
            factory.close();
        }
```

Suitable imports or JAR files for SessionFactory and Configuration()

Comment: where is the factory object declared?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no issue with jar Change your code as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create Session Factory
    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();

    // Create Session 
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
}
```